# RadioButton looks weird as soon as i add a background drawable to it

Tags: android

My RadioButtons look weird as soon as i add a background drawable to it:

Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_highlight" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_highlight" android:state_active="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_default"/>
</selector>
```

bg_highlight/bg_default are 9-patch files.

The result is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWAMB.jpg

Enclosing the RadioButtons in another view is no option obv.
Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add left padding to the radio button

```
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

set your Selector to `Button` property of radio button.

in Layout:

```
        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/off_radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/offline"
        android:button="@drawable/my_radio" />
```

my_radio.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/radio_off" />
 </selector>
```